Normal Subgroups as Subobjects
Usually, ideal objects (normals subgroups, ring ideals) are viewed as kernels of homomorphisms or objects encapsulating congruence relations. A third categorical viewpoint, however, seems particularly natural to me. In abelian categories, the ideals correspond precisely with subojects: one can quotient an object by any of its subobjects. Hence if we are able to embed an object of some category $\mathsf{C}$ into an abelian category, we get a precise and elegant description of its ideals. (I've read that the Yoneda embedding allows any category to be embedded in a functor category, although I've not yet studied it in depth and cannot speak with certainty.)
$R$-Modules most notably corroborate this point of view. Indeed, an $R$-module is simply a functor $\mathsf{R} \to \mathsf{Ab}$ where $\mathsf{R}$ is $R$ taken as a singular preadditive category. Then the functor category $\mathsf{Ab}^{\mathsf{R}}$ is abelian, so ideals of $R$ may be realized as subobjects of $R$ as an $R$-module.
Now I wonder if a similar thing can be done with groups, realizing normal subgroups as subojects of a group-as-category. I suppose a group $G$ may be similarly viewed as a $G$-set, but the resulting category is not abelian, so the situation is not much better.

Maybe worth mentioning: normal subgroups can be seen as cosubobjects in the category of groups, i.e. subobjects in the opposite category, i.e. isomorphism classes of epimorphisms $G \to G/H$. You recover the normal subgroup by taking the kernel.

A normal subgroup is, in particular, a subgroup. They are precisely the kernels of homomorphisms – also known as normal monomorphisms. There is no need to go to another category.
